# what does "-sh: executable_path:not found" mean

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux

i am trying to run an executable in linux shell ( OpenELEC on raspberry pi )

```
OpenELEC:~ # /storage/fingi/usr/lib/autossh/autossh
-sh: /storage/fingi/usr/lib/autossh/autossh: not found
```

What does the "not found" in this case mean ?

If i try to do ldd:

```
OpenELEC:~ # ldd  /storage/fingi/usr/lib/autossh/autossh
/usr/bin/ldd: eval: line 1: /storage/fingi/usr/lib/autossh/autossh: not found
```

And if i do file:

```
OpenELEC:~ # file /storage/fingi/usr/lib/autossh/autossh
/storage/fingi/usr/lib/autossh/autossh: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=599207c47d75b62ede5f214f9322ae2a18643eb7, stripped
```

The file type is in correct format . But it wont work adn wont give more descriptive error msg either.

Since openELEC is very restrictive, i had copied the autossh executable from a raspbmc installation . I have done it for several other executables as well ( screen , boost libraries etc ) and they work fine .

Can anyone suggest what might be the issue?

Edit 1:
as was suggested, this is the output of file command on an executable ( also copied from raspbmc ) that is working:

```
OpenELEC:~ # file /storage/fingi/usr/bin/screen
/storage/fingi/usr/bin/screen: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=5c58f047a25caa2c51a81d8285b4f314abc690e7, stripped
```

Comment: Maybe it suggests that the file type of the executable is not the correct type, though the message is usually something other than 'not found' when that's the problem. Find another executable (maybe `/bin/sh` and compare the type reported by `file`.

Comment: added. they are instact same

Comment: and yes i am suspecting it is architechtture issue..but it is working for all other executables!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What does the "not found" in this case mean ?

This usually means that the executable cannot find one or more (shared) libraries to satisfy its external symbols.
This usually happens when no libraries are stored in the initramfs, or there is a shared library missing that the executable needs.
This can also happen if the executable is built with a C library that is incompatible with the runtime library, e.g. uClibc versus glibc/eglibc.

`strings executable | less` is the quickest way to see the required libraries and external symbols that the executable requires.
Or
Recompile your program and use static linking by specifying the `-static` option.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the file has been set to executable permissions with `ls -l` if it hasn't change with `chmod +x /storage/fingi/usr/lib/autossh/autossh`

Comment: it has executable permission: -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       22.9K Jan 12 23:59 autossh

Comment: Try `objdump -p /path/to/program | grep NEEDED`