# Install packages on Busybox Linux

Tags: package, busybox, gdbserver

I want to install gdbserver on an Busybox Linux embedded in a Atmel `SAMA5D3x-MB` with `ARM Cortex®-A5`-based microcontroller

What I did:

find gdbserver compiled for ARM.

copy it on target at `/usr/bin.`

But when I try to execute it like this : `./gdbserver` : 
I get the error:

```
-sh: gdbserver: not found
```

Here is the exact distribution name :

```
Linux buildroot 3.10.0-00354-gdf700c9 #1 Wed Feb 19 15:28:48 CST 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does "-sh: executable\_path:not found" mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084611/what-does-sh-executable-pathnot-found-mean).  The executable that you found/installed is not compatible with the dynamic libraries installed in your board's root filesystem. The **strace** command is one way to investigate this, but many embedded systems do not have this command installed (or built into Busybox).

Comment: you were right ! I had to compile a new kernel with gdbserver as a package to use it on my target