# No such file or directory when run executable file on Embedded Linux

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, imx6

I'm working with a Target board which use micro controller MCIMX6DP6AVT8AA - i.MX 6 series 32-bit MPU, Dual ARM Cortex-A9 core, 850MHz, FCBGA 624
(refer http://www.nxp.com/webapp/search.partparamdetail.framework?PART_NUMBER=MCIMX6DP6AVT8AA). My board run Linux kernel 3.1.1

I use cross-compile toolchain arm-poky-linux-gnueabi, run on host Ubuntu14.04 to build a Application for Target board. After built successful, i checked the output file as below

> ~$ file MyApp
>
> MyApp: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1
> (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.1.1,
> BuildID[sha1]=a800b4033343517d3368a3f3ca0c87eb98f6c1ba, not stripped

But when i run it on Target board, there was error

> ~$ ./MyApp
>
> -sh: ./MyApp: No such file or directory

I don't know what i did wrong ?

Comment: Did you copy the binary `MyApp` to the board?

Comment: @snoopy: Yes, i did. I remote to board and run command to execute MyApp

Comment: did u check the permissions of the binary? Does this has execute permission?

Comment: @rk1825: Yes, i did. I use root account

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does "-sh: executable\_path:not found" mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084611/what-does-sh-executable-pathnot-found-mean)

Answer (score 2):

The message is very likely coming from the dynamic linker. Look at the output of:

```
ldd MyApp
```

It will tell you all the library dependencies and where they are found on the system. Install those which hadn't been found.

Comment: ldd not work with binary file build by arm-poky-linux-gnueabi. Do you have other suggestion ?

Comment: Good general solution to “why does this executable I can see right there ‘not exist’!!!” Thanks very much.