# -sh: /bin/fw_printenv: No such file or directory (But I m Having fw_printenv file)

Tags: filesystems, u-boot, imx6

This binary i can able to run in Normal ARM file system.
Now I m running the same binary in INITRAMFS - (Minimal filesystem)

uname -m --> results in **armv7l**

I think some libraries are missing.
Can anyone help me to reslove this issue.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084611/what-does-sh-executable-pathnot-found-mean/21131076#21131076

Comment: I compiled statically , Its working fine now... Tnx for your response