# Run executable from Buildroot rootfs

Tags: linux, executable, qemu, buildroot, rootfs

I've been using QEMU to test a prototype I'm creating and now I want to test in on a real board. I'm using Buildroot to create the rootfs for the board and, after putting the rootfs on my SD card, I put the executable on the /bin folder. However, after booting and when I try to run it I get the message '-sh: *executable*: not found'.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does "-sh: executable\_path:not found" mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084611/what-does-sh-executable-pathnot-found-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the executable wasn't build with a cross-compiler that matches the C library you have on your target.