# How to execute dynamically linked executables in BusyBox

Tags: linux, dynamic, static, kernel, busybox

I'm building a mini Embedded Linux.
I was able to get busybox installed up and running
and made a helloworld in C. I compiled it using

```
gcc -o -static hello hello.c
```

in the bin directory of busybox `__install` folder.

It ran fine and executed the hello world with the following output:
`Hello, World!`

However when I compiled it WITHOUT the static flag using:

```
gcc -o hello hello.c
```

it doesn't work. I execute it with `./hello`
and it says

```
hello not found
```

It seems like the static executables only work.. Is There a workaround for this?

Comment: The solution is to either (a) build your program with a toolchain that matches the  libraries already installed on your target, or (b) install all the necessary libraries and loader that your current toolchain uses. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084611/what-does-sh-executable-pathnot-found-mean/21131076#21131076

Comment: @sawdust I fixed it. I had to find the lib files to the application then add that to busybox.