# Cross compiling from Ubuntu 22.04 to ARM architecture not working

Tags: node.js, arm, embedded-linux, cross-compiling, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to cross compile NodeJs from Ubuntu 22.04 for ARM architecture. Tried with multiple node versions like 8.17, 12.22, 10.24

Following are set in environment

```
CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
LD=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld
CXX_host="g++ -m32"
CC_host="gcc -m32"
```

By using command:

```
./configure --dest-cpu=arm --cross-compiling --dest-os=linux --without-intl --without-dtrace
```

the output binary file type is:

```
node: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, BuildID[sha1]=fa3bb60e9c3ecef4c39de6b7a89be3eb94f957fb, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Which is not working. getting error while trying to run generated binary in board.

`./node -v`  gives error node not found.

but following file type is working.

```
node: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=525a819b3ea8436162e9e1ac1ffb94a55f405635, stripped
```

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: You repeated write that it's "*not working*', but neglect to describe what actually happens. Are there any error messages?

Comment: Edited to add error.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [what does "-sh: executable_path:not found" mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084611/what-does-sh-executable-pathnot-found-mean/21131076#21131076)?