bash: No such file or directory during a grub theme install
So im trying to install the big sur grub theme and im following the install guide:
$ git clone https://github.com/Teraskull/bigsur-grub2-theme

$ cd bigsur-grub2-theme

$ ./install.sh

and for some reason when inputting $ ./install.sh i get
bash: ./install.sh: cannot execute: required file not found

and i dont really know what to do...
(Btw im using NixOs with the grub bootloader and i also have windows 10 installed with a dual boot also heres my nix config file)

See https://superuser.com/questions/1176200/no-such-file-when-it-exists/1176328#1176328 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084611/what-does-sh-executable-pathnot-found-mean

these both give the same response but are extremely different cases, these literally have 0 correllation with my problem

Does /bin/bash exist?
